# How to declare getter function signature in interface for a mapping?

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping, interfaces

I have a `contract` that implements an `interface`, the contract has a state variable `mapping(address => bytes32[]) public usersLists`, I defined a getter function signature in the `interface` for this state variable, but I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
  --> interfaces/IPool.sol:42:65:
   |
42 |   function usersLists(address user) external view returns (bytes32[]);
   |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

The interface and contract are as follows:

```
interface IA {
  function usersLists(address user) external view returns (bytes32[]);
}

contract A is IA {
  mapping(address => bytes32[]) public override usersLists;
}
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue? It seems to be an issue with the `list` and not `bytes32` as removing `[]` making it a `mapping(address => bytes32)` removes the compiler error, but from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/56668/86303) it should be possible to return `bytes32[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic types you need to defined the storage location.

In your case `function usersLists(address user) external view returns (bytes32[] memory);`

See more information in the Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#data-location

Edit:

The question you linked used an older Solidity version, therefore it was not required there.

Edit 2:

The method in the interface does not correspond to the automatically generated getter for `mapping(address => bytes32[])`. Solidity automatically adds all "key-lookups" as a parameter to the getter function.

Here an example with the default getter that will return a `bytes32` and the custom getter that returns the whole array:

```js
interface IA {
  // Getter that will be generated automatically
  function usersLists(address user, uint256 index) external view returns (bytes32);
  // Custom getter
  function getUsersLists(address user) external view returns (bytes32[] memory);
}

contract A is IA {
  mapping(address => bytes32[]) public override usersLists;

  function getUsersLists(address user) external override view returns (bytes32[] memory) {
        return usersLists[user];
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, however I have tried adding both memory and calldata and I still get compiler errors, you can verify in Remix using my example interface and contract.

Comment: The default getter generated for a mapping to an array is different. I will adjust my answer